# Reading data from data acquisition unit (measurement computing)

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, data-acquisition

I have a data acquisition unit (USB-2408 from Measurement Computing) and am trying to write Python code to display that data in as close to real-time as I can, but obviously that's limited, so I'll take what I can get.  I ran across a man that has [already done this, almost](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Data_Acquisition_with_PyUL).

So I found his [PyUL site](https://code.astraw.com/PyUniversalLibrary/) and tried some of the example code he has (copied and pasted it straight into a .py file and threw it in my relevant directory. When I call the code through cmd (`...\Python27\Lib\site-packages\sciypy>python example1.py`) I get an error code :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "daq-scipy1.py", line 3, in <module>
    import UniversalLibrary as UL
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packaget__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from UniversalLibrary import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packagersalLibrary.py", line 53, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 168, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .npyio import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import format
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\format.py", line 141, in <module>
    import io
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\io\__init__.py" line 85, in <module>
    from .matlab import loadmat, savemat, whosmat, byteo
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .mio import loadmat, savemat, whosmat
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\mio.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scipy.lib.six import string_types
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    from numpy import oldnumeric
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\oldnumeric\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .compat import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-package\numpy\oldnumeric\compat.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import functions
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\oldnumeric\functions.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .typeconv import convtypecode, convtypecode2
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\oldnumeric\typeconv.py", line 7, in <module>
    oldtype2dtype = {'1': np.dtype(np.byte),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

Is there a file or module maybe that I haven't installed that would keep this from running or similar solution/workaround?  I ran this code just to see if I could handle the data coming from the unit in a way separate to the software they provide with the unit. If thereis a better way, please inform me. I have already tried pySerial, pywinusb or d2xx and others like pywin32 to no avail. The unit is listed in device manager these days as a completely new device class: DAS Component, older units used to be under USB Human Interface Devices.

Relevant Info: Python2.7 (32-bit) on Windows 8

Comment: It doesn't address your question, but Measurement Computing  does not care about Python. If you want to use Python, go LabJack, they are very responsive and sometimes even fun: https://github.com/labjack/LabJackPython

Comment: @DavClark: Went with MMC due to design criteria, though LabJack does look "fun" thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't reached the bottom of this problem yet, but it looks like a problem with `numpy` because Python cannot find a `dtype` attribute in `np`, which is how `numpy` is imported into the file `oldnumeric/typeconv.py` within the `numpy` distribution.

I suspect one of:

1. A corrupted `numpy` distribution (in which case you would be best to re-install `numpy`), or
2. A name space conflict of some sort.

`numpy` has test code for `dtype` (it is in `../numpy/core/tests/test_dtype.py`) so you could run the `numpy` test suite and see if it throws an error relating to `dtype`.

The other thing I've noticed is that the PyUL code uses the old [Numeric](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jrennie/python/numeric/) package, which may perhaps be conflicting with `numpy`

Comment: I think you were right.  I found another way to get numpy and re-installed.  The code runs okay, but I think it's a case of new board, old code.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to help. If you've solved the problem you could check this answer as correct.